# Is there anything wrong with this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, grammaticality

> In December it'll be 3 years since I have been trying to learn this
> language.

Is there anything wrong with this sentence? My friend said it, but I think it should be "In December I'll have been trying to learn this language for 3 years."

Comment: _Since_ is used with a particular starting point, so it should be "...since I started trying to learn this language". Your version is fine too.

Comment: I'd cut the unnecessary words -- "As of December, I've been learning this language for three years."